# Ajax Call going to Error Block without any obvious reasons

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call to my php backend server file. However the call returns an undefined object and goes to error function without indicating why. I am unable to figure out the problem.

Here's the ajax call:

```
function getStationList(){

        console.log("Station List");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dist/php/charts_data.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {functionname: 'getStationsData', arguments: 'na'},
            
            success: function(obj){

                stations = obj.stationList;
                stationIDs = obj.stationID;
                stationCount = obj.row_count;

                setStationOptions(0);
            },
            error: function(obj){
              console.log("1");
              console.log(obj.error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Since the php file will have multiple different database call functions, I put the functions in a switch case, like below:

```
switch($_POST['functionname']){

        case 'getStationsData':
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Conf_Station";
            $params = array();
            $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);


            $aResult['row_count'] = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
            $aResult['stationList'] = array();
            $aResult['stationID'] = array();
    
            while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
              array_push($aResult['stationList'],$row['Station']);
              array_push($aResult['stationID'],$row['StationID']);
            }
            sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

        break;

        default: $aResult['error'] = 'Not found function '.$_POST['functionname'].'!'; 
    }
```

But executing the above gives me this:

Console Message

[image]

I am at a loss. Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: You have you return the ``$aResult`` to front-end code via **echo** or **print_r** statement, after **json encoding**.

Comment: `console.log(obj.error);` is wrong. Read https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR and tell us where it says that the jqXHR object passed into the error function contains an "error" property? There's a list of properties it **does** return...try one of those instead. Also please use your browser's Network tool to see what happened to the request - you can see the status it came back with, and also go into it to see the raw response.

Comment: Also as the first comment says, it's not clear if/where in the PHP you actually echo a JSON response back to the browser.